# only update key in dictionary from another dictionary as reference

Tags: python-3.6

For simplicity, i have 2 dictionaries below. i want to update the second dictionary (but only the keys) and set the value to 0 in reference to the first dictionary.

original dictionaries:

```
dict1={'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
dict2 ={'a': 2, 'b': 2}
```

after update:

```
dict1 ={'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
dict2 ={'a': 2, 'b': 2, 'c': 0}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dict2.update` with a dict comprehension to do this:

```
dict1={'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
dict2 ={'a': 2, 'b': 2}

dict2.update({k:0 for k,v in dict1.items() if k not in dict2})

print (dict1)
print (dict2)
```

> ```
> {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
> {'a': 2, 'b': 2, 'c': 0}
> ```